# Select graphics card

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, kvm, pci-passthrough

Is there a way to select a primary graphics other than onboard graphics?
I have two different dedicated graphics cards in my machine, one GT640 and a GTX970. I am trying to set up the machine to set up Linux Mint to use the GT640 and later I will enable GPU passthrough to a KVM Windows VM for the GTX970. However currently I can only get the system to boot on the GTX970 not the other graphics card, and the graphics drivers are not working with the other graphics card anyway.

Things I have tried:

- Installing Mint then connecting to the GTX970, however it always starts trying to use the new card instantly.
- I also get a blank output on the GTX970 even with `nomodeset` enabled. However ideally I don't want the Linux Mint  host to touch the GTX970 anyway other than for KVM to pass it to Windows.

Does anyone have any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: have you tried swapping the cards into each other's PCI-e slots?  it may be that the system is booting on the 970 because it is detecting it first (due to it being in a lower numbered pci slot).  worth testing, anyway.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet but I will, I just more less placed the bigger card in a slot where I felt it would get more airflow

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to put the card in another slot because of the way the SATA connectors are positioned, the card would block the connectors, I did make progress though by booting my old card first long enough to install nvidia drivers for Linux, and then putting the GTX970 back in.

Comment: does it boot now with both cards and the proprietary nvidia drivers rather than nouveau?

Comment: It is booting with the correct drivers, and both card are detected but I only get output from the gtx970

Comment: Have you tried adding a `BusID "bus-id"` option (where "bus-id" is the pci bus id of your GT640 from, e.g., `lspci`) to the Devices section in your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`?  Given your unusual situation (two video cards, but you only want to use one in linux itself) you can't get away with not having an `xorg.conf` file and relying on the default/detected settings.  You need to tell X explicitly what to do and which card to use.  See `man xorg.conf`.  And you'll also have to read the docs for the `nvidia` proprietary driver.

Comment: FYI, these may help: https://wiki.debian.org/VGAPassthrough and https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=212692 and https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/

Comment: Thank You, Its working now, i3 is using the gt640, if i go to a tty shell it still comes up on the GTX970 but the system shows the card as unused, hopefully it wont interfere as long as I don't open a tty.